# Can Mathematica interpret Condensed formula?

Tags: chemistry

Im trying to Create a molecule using a condensed formula as input.I tried some other condensed formulas but it always get an unevaluated Result:

```
Molecule["(CH3)2CHOH"]
```

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: How would it know whether you meant [isopropanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol) or [methoxyethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methoxyethane)? Maybe it is refusing to evaluate because of this ambiguity.

Comment: @Roman:Isnt ethyl methyl ether condensed formula CH3OCH2CH3?

Comment: @Arman, that's correct. Still, the fact remains that `Molecule[]` is not equipped to interpret those. If you wish, [send a suggestion to WRI](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried SMILES or Canonical SMILES? They are defined much more rigorously, and allow the distinction between isopropanol and methoxyethane:

```
Molecule["C(C(C([H])([H])[H])(O[H])[H])([H])([H])[H]"]
(*    isopropanol    *)

Molecule["CC(C)O"]
(*    isopropanol    *)

Molecule["C(C(OC([H])([H])[H])([H])[H])([H])([H])[H]"]
(*    methoxyethane    *)

Molecule["CCOC"]
(*    methoxyethane    *)
```

Comment: Apart from SMILES, `Molecule[]` can also interpret [InChI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Chemical_Identifier) (`Molecule["InChI=1S/C3H8O/c1-3(2)4/h3-4H,1-2H3"]`). It uses [OPSIN](https://opsin.ch.cam.ac.uk) for this, so any format that can't be parsed by OPSIN will likely fail.